# Can child work items state change automatically when parent state changes

Tags: tfs, workflow

I have the same states and transitions defined for two type of work items (User Story and Task) and I would like when some work item is transitioned in that particular state that all child work items that have the same state and transitions are set with this state.

Example: 
User Story and Task have state Postponed, and for example I have User Story that have 3 child work items, when I change state of parent User Story to Postponed all child work items that have state Postponed are changed automatically to state Postponed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly useful functionality but currently there's no support for it. You can use the TFS-API to invoke state changes. This [post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=336) provides a related example.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do this if you want to build a server-side extension.  My suggestion would be to go the [ISubscriber](http://colinsalmcorner.blogspot.com/2011/12/isubscriber-getting-tfs-url-for-client.html) route by compiling a plug-in DLL and putting it in the plug-ins folder on each application tier server.  We have some additional information about creating `ISubscriber`'s in Chapter 25 of our book, [Professional Team Foundation Server 2010](http://bit.ly/TFS2010Book) by Wrox.